# How do you hide Windows 7 Explorer Toolbar and Property Bar?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In Windows 7, Windows Explorer has a large bar just above the status bar that contains properties of the highlighted item. Is it possible to hide this? It  takes up a significant amount of screen space I'd prefer using in the file listing.

Also, is it possible to hide the tool bar for the same reason? That's what I'm calling the bar near the top with "Organize, Open, Include in Library, Share With..."

Comment: I have not tried this myself, but it looks like [this tutorial](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/65416-window-explorer-toolbar-remove.html) explains how to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: According to [this Microsoft page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/working-with-files-folders#1TC=windows-7&section_2) (in particular, [this image](http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/e1cc646e-5a59-48c6-a52b-97153bfdb767_49.jpg)), the bottom bar above the status bar is called **Details pane**; the toolbar near the top under the menu bar is called, simply, **Toolbar**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Organize → Layout → Details pane

And no, I don't think you can hide the toolbar in Explorer windows.

Comment: This did it for the bottom. I never did see how to get rid of the bar that has "Organize" in it, but I got rid of the menu bar instead. I can right-click and access everything I need from the menu, and the "Organize..." bar only takes a little more space than the menu bar.

Comment: Well, the menu bar is hidden by default anyway. The tool bar (the thing that has »Organize« in it) apparently can't be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows 7 Command Bar Tweaker](http://yvidhiatama.deviantart.com/art/Windows-7-Command-Bar-Tweaker-254892578) can be used to hide the Windows 7 Explorer toolbar (or Command bar).

Comment: That looks good. Unfortunately, I have the aero theme disabled.

Comment: This link is dead, does anybody have a mirror?

Comment: Found it at the bottom link of this page. <https://techdows.com/2011/08/auto-hidedisableremove-the-command-bar-in-windows-7-explorer-with-windows-7-command-bar-tweaker.html>. If the link dies again you should be able to use the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?:

http://www.winvistaclub.com/t219.html

It claims it's working for vista and 7.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Win 7 -- couldn't find gpedit.msc.

Comment: Editing group policies isn't possible in the Home versions of Vista or Win 7.

Comment: I think this link changed -- it's got Windows Pinball now.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "Folder Band".

This link will tell you how to do so, except it shows you how to auto-hide.
[customize it](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-customize-windows-explorer-command-bar-aka-folder-band-or-toolbar-in-windows-vista-and-7-add-cut-copy-paste-delete-rename-undo-and-many-other-useful-buttons/)

If you want to remove it permanently, read the link and instead of doing their modification, replace this:

```
<style resid="FolderBandStyle">
<Element
background="argb(0, 0, 0, 0)"
/>
```

with:

```
<style resid="FolderBandStyle">
<Element
background="argb(0, 0, 0, 0)"
padding="rect(0rp,0rp,0rp,-28rp)" />
```

Once finished you can just restart explorer.exe, you don't have to restart as the article suggests.