# Explorer: Remove Top Banner/Navigation

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, gui

Can you inform me how to remove the top banner (navigation) in Windows Explorer?  OS is Windows 7.

[image: Explorer Screenshot]

Comment: I don't think you can actually do this. Removing that banner would remove key functionalities of Explorer. So I doubt theres a way to remove it.

Comment: Guess not. Similar one: http://superuser.com/questions/114954/how-do-you-hide-windows-7-explorer-toolbar-and-property-bar

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it using the Registry Editor. With Admin privileges you can go here

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Toolbar\ShellBrowser]

Then change the number in bold to either 00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00 to hide the menu and buttons or 03,00,00,00,00,00,00,00 to hide only menu.

This advice is from the [Microsoft website for IT Pros](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/987305c6-bd48-4107-bcf5-84d4fff4097d/hide-windows-explorer-address-bar?forum=winserverGP)