# How to hide bottom panel on "my computer" in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows

upon opening "My computer" there is the bottom panel with information about processor and RAM. How can I hide or delete this information or remove the whole bottom panel?

Answer (score 3):

Open your Windows Explorer, navigate to this option and uncheck it

```
Organize → Layout → Details pane
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/114954/how-do-you-hide-windows-7-explorer-toolbar-and-property-bar)